# query search url match

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a DB table with one of the column as **URL** have row values as

```
http://wwww.yahoo.com
http://google.com 
http://englishclub.de
```

Can anyone suggest sql query to retrieve rows only which match domain names by ignoring www/http/:/ ?

This is for autocomplete i e if user type 'go' , it should retrieve http://google.com

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select replace(replace(URL,'http://',''),'www.','')
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to replace values, just select rows while disregarding the http://

Comment: yes you can use wild card as follows: select * from table where replace(replace(URL,'http://',''),'www.','') like '%go%'

Comment: why on earth would you use REPLACE function when he is just doing a wildcard select? It would be quite slow on larger tables

Answer (score -2):

Here:

```
SELECT * FROM DBTABLE WHERE FIELD LIKE '%google.com%';
```

Note, the % is a wild card